# OOP Casting class member to another class

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have parent class Ad with 2 children Direct and Adword. On the other side I have parent class Campaign with 2 children DirectCampaign and AdwordsCampaign. Campaign class contains array of corresponding Ad children instances.

```
class Ad:
    def __init__(self, keyword, negative_keywords, url):
        self.keyword = keyword
        self.negative_keywords = negative_keywords
        self.url = url


class Direct(Ad):

   def __init__(self, keyword, negative_keywords, headline, description, url):

        super().__init__(keyword, negative_keywords, url)

        self.url_with_utm = url + "?"


class Adword(Ad):

    def __init__(self, keyword, negative_keywords, headline1, headline2, description, url):

       super().__init__(keyword, negative_keywords, url)


class Campaign():
    ads = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add(self, ad):
        self.ads.append(ad)


class DirectCampaign(Campaign):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)


class AdwordsCampaign(Campaign):
    pass


def main():
    direct = DirectCampaign("adv_search")
    direct.import_from_csv('direct.csv')
```

My primary goal is to cast DirectCampaign to AdwordsCampaign, but I cannot understand how to do it according to OOP(what class should have such method, should I call AdwordsCampaign constructor there and Adwords constructor after).

Secondary goal is DirectCampain has name attribute, how I can access it in Direct instance? Should I pass it through constructor to every Direct instance?

Any feedback for the code is welcome.

Comment: Please trim your code snippet down to [MCVE] that exposes your issue.